# regex: how to grab times from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, cheerio

I'm working on a scraper for [The List](http://www.foopee.com/punk/the-list/by-date.0.html) as a JS project, and my regex-fu could be better than it is.

Given a data structure like

```
<a name="may_21"><b>Wed May 21</b></a>
<ul>
<li><b><a href="by-club.0.html#Ace_of_Spades__Sacramento">Ace of Spades, Sacramento</a></b> <a href="by-band.0.html#Christina_Perri">Christina Perri</a>, <a href="by-band.0.html#Birdy">Birdy</a> a/a $20 7pm **
...
</ul>
```

I've written the following to leverage cheerio to grab a date, venue, and list of bands:

```
request(url, (error, response, html)->
    if(!error)
        $ = cheerio.load(html)

        concert = { bands : {}, location : {venue: "", address : ""}, date: {date: "", time: ""}}

        calendar = {}

        dates = []

        #grab dates
        $('body > ul > li > a').each(->
            data = $(this)
            $dates = data.children().first()
            dates.push($dates.text())
        )

        #build concerts
        for date in dates
            $("a:contains('" + date + "')").siblings().each(->
                $venue = $(this).children().find("b")
                $bands = $venue.siblings("a")
                $time = $venue.parent()#.match()
            )

)
```

As you can see, I'm having trouble figuring out how to grab the time from the above structure.

Typically, that is going to be a bit of plain text at the end of a `li` that corresponds to a specific show, so that for something like

**Bottom of the Hill, S.F.** Matt Pond PA, Lighthouse And The Whaler, Kyle M. Terrizzi a/a $14/$16 8pm/9pm **

I would be looking to grab the "8pm/9pm" text out of

```
<li><b><a href="by-club.0.html#Bottom_of_the_Hill__S_F_">Bottom of the Hill, S.F.</a></b> <a href="by-band.2.html#Matt_Pond_PA">Matt Pond PA</a>, <a href="by-band.2.html#Lighthouse_And_The_Whaler">Lighthouse And The Whaler</a>, <a href="by-band.1.html#Kyle_M__Terrizzi">Kyle M. Terrizzi</a> a/a $14/$16 8pm/9pm **
```

Sometimes it will be in the form of "8pm", sometimes "8pm/9m" and sometimes it won't be there at all.

What's the best way to structure a regex to grab this data?

Comment: From looking at the page you link to, there are more time formats than you describe here. As a first step, please write down an exhaustive list of every kind of input format you expect and exactly what value(s) you expect to retrieve from each of them.

Comment: don't regex the full raw html (general advice). Instead, try loading the html to a temporary container-div (or `documentFragment` but you need some custom basic getter-shims). Now work your way (loop) through the known structure, discard everything you don't need (like anchors) and finally loop through the containers to grab your final data (using a much simpler regex, that matches `/(\d+[ap]m/?){1,2}$/i` (and what Tomalak said, I figured you already researched your expected formats). PS,word from a scraper: you only know your final routine once you fully and succesfully completed your scrape!

Comment: You are welcome! I put it up as answer for your consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Don't regex the full raw html (general advice).

Instead, try loading the html to a temporary container-div (or `documentFragment` but you need some custom basic getter-shims).

Now work your way (loop) through the known structure, discarding everything you don't need (like anchors) and finally loop through the containers (in what's left over) to grab your final data (using a much simpler regex, that matches for example: `/(\d+[ap]m/?){1,2}$/i`.

PS, a word from a scraper: you often only know your final routine once you fully and successfully completed your scrape! (Like you usually find lost stuff in the last place you look..).
As Tomalak commented: pitfall no 1: data that doesn't match what you anticipate. Try to research your expected data-formats!!

**EDIT:**
Extra advice: add as much error-checking you can. Try to translate every flaw you find during testing to a check. You *NEED* any help you can get once you start scraping massive amounts of data.

Consider a chunking-approach : If a check fails, you don't need to start over from the beginning of the data. Instead, add extra check/solution and continue your scrape.
Otherwise just testing/debugging your scraper might even look like DOS behavior/traffic.

Comment: awesome, thanks -- any advice for a library of shims / examples?

Comment: no, sorry. each scraper is a custom job. However, here is a pretty sweet scraper I did recently (that radio-station is now down): *full h4xed playlist from 8 dec 2013 (now generates more stats and has basic file-size estimation routine): http://fiddle.jshell.net/k3DDr/1/show/  (this playlist was scraped with the updated scraper: http://fiddle.jshell.net/433Zp/8/show/ )* (PS: Andy knows, I shared it in aid of rescuing the now dead station's playlist) This is probably a better solution (hint hint) and has most basic needs covered (but not as a library).

Answer (score 0):

got this working, here's the code that I ended up using

```
fs = require('fs')
request = require('request')
cheerio = require('cheerio')
crypto = require("crypto")

url = 'http://www.foopee.com/punk/the-list/by-date.0.html'

getConcertItem = (text, regex)->
    return text.match(regex)?.toString().replace(/,/g, '').trim()

request(url, (error, response, html)->
    if(!error)
        $ = cheerio.load(html)

        #print(html)

        calendar = {}

        $dates = $('body > ul > li')

        #dates
        $dates.each(->

            date = $(this).find("a").first().text()

            $concerts = $(this).children("ul").children()

            $concerts.each( ->

                #todo: use the import-style ID generator
                ID = parseInt(crypto.randomBytes(4).toString('hex'), 16)

                concert = {bands : [], location : {venue: "", address : ""}, date: {date: "", time: ""}, cost: "", allAges: false}

                $venue = $(this).find("b")
                concert.location.venue = $venue.text()

                concertText = $venue.parent().clone().children().remove().end().text()

                timeRegex = /(\d?:?\d+[ap]m\/?\s?\w*\s?)/g
                concert.date.date = date
                concert.date.time = getConcertItem(concertText, timeRegex)

                costRegex = /(\$\d+[\/-]?)/g
                concert.cost = getConcertItem(concertText, costRegex)

                allAgesRegex = /(a\/a)/g
                if getConcertItem(concertText, allAgesRegex)
                    concert.allAges = true

                $bands = $venue.siblings()
                bands = []
                $bands.each( ->
                    band = $(this).text()
                    bands.push(band)
                )
                concert.bands = bands

                calendar[ID] = concert

            )


        )

)
```